# SignalR Chat Logging

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have written a basic chat application using MVC and SignalR.  I have the requirement of keeping a chat log.  What would be the best way of accomplishing this?

I am leaning towards using a sql database, but am open to any and all suggestions.

EDIT: 
To make the question more specific:  What would the advantages of using a sql database be vs other methods?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have experience with SQL, using a SQL DB makes sense. I'm sure you can find higher-level logging solutions, but there are benefits to using what you know. Most popular SQL DBs should be easy and flexible enough for the job.

Comment: That's a great point.  I edited my question for clarity and because I was asking for opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning on hosting it in Windows Azure, you should probably use table storage instead of a SQL database. Last I checked, Azure storage was much cheaper than SQL storage, so if you're not using the relational capabilities, it makes sense to not have to pay for them.